# How to send parameters along with a POST http request in node?

Tags: node.js

This is my code I have written .

```
var querystring = require('querystring');

var http = require('http');
var body = querystring.stringify({
      B1: 'Submit',
      RollNumber: 12569

});

var request = http.request({
    host: '14.139.56.15',
    port: 443,
    path: '/scheme12/studentresult/details.asp',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)
        }

    }, function(res,err) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log('Getting response..');
            var resp = '';
            res.on('data', function(data) {
                resp += data;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                console.log(resp);


            });
            res.on('error', function(err) {
                winston.error(err);
            });


    request.write(body);
    request.end();
});
```

It is giving me this error

`Error: read ECONNRESET`

I am doing this for the first time and don't know whether I am doing this right or not . You can visit the link and check it out . I need to get the data out of this form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to submit an HTTP request to a site listening on an HTTPS port (443). Change `var http = require('http');` to `var http = require('https');` (and the variable name to match if you like).

Comment: Just to add, he should also move his write/end methods outside of the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I did what you said . Now am getting this error -  `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` .

Comment: @BenFortune Thanks . I moved it out of the callback .

Comment: Finally everything worked. Added this -->  `"rejectUnauthorized": false`